# Decode S-JIS string to UTF-8

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a Japanese File and I have no knowledge of the language. The file is encoded in S-JIS. Now, I am supposed to convert the contents into UTF-8 so that the content looks like Japanese. And here I am completely blank. I tried the following code that I found somewhere on Internet but no luck:

```
byte[] arrByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(arrActualData[x]);
string str = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(arrByte);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance
Kunal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the following code works for me. 
I wanted to try this out so evidence of my results below:

```
public void Convert()
{
   using (TextReader input = new StreamReader(
     new FileStream("shift-jis.txt", FileMode.Open), 
       Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis")))
   {
      using (TextWriter output = new StreamWriter(
        new FileStream("utf8.txt", FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
      {
        var buffer = new char[512];
        int len;

        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 512)) > 0)
        {
          output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Shown here is the file encoded in *shift-jis* (or SJIS/Shift_JIS [they are the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS)), using [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) to verify the encoding (the word in the file is the japanese text テスト meaning *test*):
[image]

After running the code & opening the file written to (*utf8.txt*) :
[image]

But it should be said that such a file conversion does not strictly require knowledge of any language.